# Am I doing this relations question correctly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let S = {a,b,c}. Recall that a relation on S is a subset of S×S. Give
an example of a relation R on S that is reflexive and:

a. Symmetric but not anti-symmetric.

b. Anti-symmetric but not symmetric.

c. Neither symmetric nor anti-symmetric.

d. Both symmetric and anti-symmetric.

My Answer:

S = {a,b,c}

Relation: = ‘|x| – |y| = 0’

```
a. Reflexive: ∀ a,b ∈ S, |a| – |b| = |a| – |b|
    Symmetric: ∀ a,b ∈ S, |a| – |b| = 0 then |b| – |a| = 0
    Not antisymmetric: ∀ a,b ∈ S, if |a| – |b| = 0 and |a| – |b| = 0, a ≠ b
```

Relation = ‘≤’

```
b. Reflexive: ∀ a ∈ S, a ≤ a
   Antisymmetric: ∀ a,b ∈ S, if a ≤ b and y ≤ x then a = b
   Not symmetric: ∀ a,b ∈ S, if a ≤ b, it does not guarantee b ≤ a
                    i.e. 1 ≤ 2 but 2 ≤ 1 is false
```

Relation = ‘x – y = 1’

```
c. Reflexive: ∀ a,b ∈ S, a – b = a – b
   Not Symmetric: ∀ a,b ∈ S, if a – b = 1 it does noes guarantee that b – a = 1
                    i.e. 3 – 2 = 1 but 2 – 3 = -1
   Not Antisymmetric: ∀ a,b ∈ S, if a – b = 1 and b – a = 1 then a ≠ b
```

Relation = ‘=‘

```
d. Reflexive: ∀ a ∈ S, a = a
    Symmetric: ∀ a,b ∈ S, if a = b then b = a
    Antisymmetric: ∀ a,b ∈ S, if a = b and b = a then a = b
```

Comment: $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$???

Comment: **Reality Check:** None of these answers give *an example subset of* $S{\times}S$ , as was asked.

Comment: Your understanding of "reflexive" appears to be correct in examples b and d, but not in examples a and c.

Comment: You might consider defining a relation as a *subset of $S\times S$* as opposed to a stated rule.  Giving it a symbol such as $\leq$ or $\simeq$ might not make sense in this context as you are doing here.  How do you know that $a$ and $b$ can be subtracted for example?

Answer (score 0):

No.  You were asked for *examples of relations for $S$*.  You require then subsets of $S{\times}S$

> a. (Reflexive and )Symmetric but not anti-symmetric.

$$\{(a,a), (b,b), (b,c), (c,b), (c,c)\}$$

Because:

- reflexive means that for all $x$ then $R(x,x)$ so we need the three 'diagonal' elements. $$\forall x: R(x,x)$$
- symmetry means that for all $x,y$ then: $R(x,y)\iff R(y,x)$ $$\forall x~\forall y~\big(R(x,y)\to R(y,x)$$
- antisymetric means that whenever $x\neq y$ and $R(x,y)$ then $\lnot R(y,x)$ BUT we want this to *not* be the case : so there must be at least one counter example.  $$\exists x~\exists y~\big(x\neq y\wedge R(x,y)\wedge R(y,x)\big)$$

Comment: Thanks. I understand what reflexive, symmetric and antisymmetric are but I wasn't sure how to answer the question. Now I understand the whole meaning behind (a,a),(b,b),etc. Thanks for the help!